# como ter a data atual com angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Como ter o retorno da data atual via javascript, na classe time-label
pode usar jquery ou angular.

A idéia é ter a ultima data de atualização.

Se alguém souber fico grato.

Não pode inserir o valor direto, tem que ser criado alguma função que em tempo de execução adicione a data..

em uma classe html:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="pull-left time-label"></span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="toggle-legend visible-lg pull-left cLineSwap">Legend</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você que dar uma classe ao elemento que seja uma data? pode dar um exemplo do formato que quer ter?

Comment: Na verdade @Sergio, quero que uma função crie independende to formato. apenas adicione a data atual via jquery ou angular. Se ajudar, eu vi algo nesse sentido:  $("#"+keyword_idDiv+ " .pull-left.verizon-widget-time-label").html("Last Updated: " + lastUpdated); com o jquery

Comment: Ok, e de onde vem essa data? Você muda no HTML? no script? ou vem da base de dados?

Comment: O Javascript tem que gerar, ou usar o angularJS pra gerar essa data. É algo dinamico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar assim: http://jsfiddle.net/dZSL4/

```
function dataHoje() {
    var data = new Date();
    var dia = data.getDate();
    var mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
    var ano = data.getFullYear();
    return [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
}
$('.time-label').html('Ultima atualização: ' + dataHoje());
```

Em javascript a data ter de ser "partida" em dia, mês e ano para poder ser formatada dessa maneira.

Answer (score 1):

Boa alternativa seria utilizar [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/), tem inúmeras configurações e saídas.
Baixe o pacote com as ***langs***, para que possa usar o `moment.lag('pt-br');` que é formato pt-br (Brasil).

*Vou colocar o que você pediu com vários estilos:*

***Html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        moment.lang('pt-br');
        $("#DataAtual0").html(moment().format("L"));
        $("#DataAtual1").html(moment().format('L'));
        $("#DataAtual2").html(moment().format('l'));
        $("#DataAtual3").html(moment().format('LL'));
        $("#DataAtual4").html(moment().format('ll'));
        $("#DataAtual5").html(moment().format('LLL'));
        $("#DataAtual6").html(moment().format('lll'));
        $("#DataAtual7").html(moment().format('LLLL'));
        $("#DataAtual8").html(moment().format('llll'));
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="DataAtual0"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual1"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual2"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual3"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual4"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual5"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual6"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual7"></div>
    <div id="DataAtual8"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Exemplo:*** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruxohpotter/AHVce/)

Referências:

- [Moment.js Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/)